# API works in POSTMAN not in Retrofit android

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I am integrating [Napster API](https://developer.napster.com/api/v2.2#member-favorites)! which require a bearer access token and json with Content Type. I am gving all information but I always receive 400 "Bad request" error.

this is My Retrofit Class.

```
object RetrofitClientInstance {
private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

val retrofitInstance: Retrofit
    get() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL_Secure)
                .client(provideOkHttpClient())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }
        return retrofit!!
    }


private fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {

    var logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor(object : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
        override fun log(message: String) {
            Log.d("qweqwe", message)
        }
    })
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC)
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(logging)
        .addNetworkInterceptor(
            object : Interceptor {
                @Throws(IOException::class)
                override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

                    val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .build()
                    return chain.proceed(request)
                }
            }
        )

        .build()
    return client
}
```

This is Favorite API Interface

```
@POST("/v2.2/me/favorites")
fun setFavorite(
    @Header("Authorization") accessToken: String,
    @Body favorites: JSONObject
): Call<JsonElement>
```

this is the function I am calling..

```
  private fun setFav(){
    val retrofit  = RetrofitClientInstance.retrofitInstance

    var jsonObject =  JSONObject()
    jsonObject.put("id",track.id)
    var jsonArray = JSONArray()
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject)

    var jsonObject1 = JSONObject()
    jsonObject1.put("favorites", jsonArray)

    val loginAPI = retrofit.create(TrackAPI::class.java)
    val call = loginAPI.setFavorite("Bearer ZTM0NjgyODAtOTY0OS00MTZmLTllYmQtMTMzYWM3M2VhMjkz", jsonObject1)

    call.enqueue(
        object : Callback<JsonElement> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonElement>, t: Throwable) {
                t.stackTrace
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonElement>, response: Response<JsonElement>) {

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    var jsonElement: JsonElement? = response.body()
                    if (jsonElement != null) {
                        //Rest of the code
                    }
                }
            }
        })
}
```

this is the postman response.

Postman Image -->https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjkc2.png

I am sending json object and receiving a json element.
Please give me solution.thanks in advance

Comment: How are you calling setFavorite with 2 arguments when it has 3 with no default values? Could it be that you have another setFavorite function in the TrackAPI interface?

Comment: I correct it. I am trying this way but no solution

Comment: anyone? help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost near to success. But the way you send parameter to API is wrong using Retrofit. You mistook [`org.json.JSONObject`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/json/JSONObject.html) with [`com.google.gson.JsonObject`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html).

That API requires a JSON body as a parameter like below

```
{
   "favorites": [
        {
          "id": "alb.54719066"
        }
   ]
}
```

With Retorfit library you're using `GSONConvertorFactory` to convert JSON to POJO and POJO to JSON vice-versa. In order to solve your problem you just need to change the JSON Object class imports in the API interface and Activity/Fragment. That's it!

In the API interface file

```
@POST("/v2.2/me/favorites")
fun setFavorite(
   @Header("Authorization") accessToken: String,
   @Body favorites: JsonObject   /* change from JSONObject to JsonObject */
): Call<JsonElement>
```

And inside Activity/Fragment do the changes like below,

```
private fun setFav() {

       // code...
   val retrofit  = RetrofitClientInstance.retrofitInstance

   var jsonObject =  JsonObject()   /* change from JSONObject to JsonObject */

   jsonObject.addProperty("id",track.id)   /* change from add() to addProperty() */

   var jsonArray = JsonArray()   /* change from JSONArray to JsonArray */

   jsonArray.add(jsonObject)    /* change from put() to add() */

   var jsonObject1 = JsonObject()   /* change from JSONObject to JsonObject */

   jsonObject1.add("favorites", jsonArray)  /* change from put() to add() */

       // code...
}
```

For all of these changes you have to use `import com.google.gson.*` package.

PS: Please read the code comments carefully. Import appropriate package, use proper methods and you're ready to test the changes.